# ag-grid Server Side pagination set last row independently

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I am using `ag-grid`, `Angular 7` and the **server-side** datasource with pagination.

The way my api works is that I fire two requests, the first one gives me the total table item count, and the second retrieves the desire page data.

For now, I am waiting for the count request response, and  setting up the datasource, firing the request that gets the data.

The only way I know to tell the grid the total items count is through
`params.successCallback(data, lastRow)`

Is it possible to set the last row independently ? For example with a `setLastRow()` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, there is now way to set the number of rows other than setting it `successCallback()` method. Please don't use Viewport RowModel as suggested in another response here, it's not a good reason to jump row models!, just keep the row count stored in your app, and pass it to `successCallback()` when you do call it.

Comment: Could you provide some code of how you "just keep the row count stored in your app, and pass it to successCallback()"?

Answer (score 0):

Method

```
// datasource calls this method when the total row count changes. 
// This in turn sets the height of the grids vertical scroll.
setRowCount: (count:number) => void;
```

available in View Port Row Model.

If you can switch to it, you could set total count before your retrieve data.

more here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-viewport/